# What does "In the last two days" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Hello can anybody explain what do THE LAST TWO DAYS represent?

When a person asks me for example: What have you been doing in the last two days?

Does he mean today + yesterday OR two previous days before today?

or Show me the movies that were released in the last two years. Should I show him current year + last year or two previous years?

Does somebody understand what I am asking? Thanks for help! Please explain.

Comment: This is a bit like asking how long a piece of string is. If the person is asking you on 31 December 2017 about the last two years, you may safely assume 2016 & 2017. If the question comes on 1 January 2017, it refers to 2015 and 2016. Whether the question concerns calendar years or merely periods of 12 months is moot. That's to say: the answer depends.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the preceding 48 hours, which could refer to the current day if it is late enough. If someone said "the last two days" at 8 am, it would typically not be assumed that he was talking about the current day.

Answer (score 2):

To a great extent, this is context-dependent - it depends largely on when the question is being asked.

If you're being asked in the morning, then the questioner is probably asking about your actions yesterday and the day before. If being asked in the afternoon or evening, it probably refers to today and yesterday.

Last two years is similar, though given the length of time and the number of events that can happen in two years, they're likely asking about the last 24 months, rather than calendar years.